# Ubuntu - My /var/wiki folder has gone missing. Is this a Linux issue?

Tags: ubuntu, debian

I implemented a few installations of mediawiki in a parent folder called: /var/wiki

I was alerted this morning that the wikis are no longer working.

Upon a little research, the /var/wiki folder is gone.

Is there any Linux-based reason why this folder would be removed?

If not, I'll look at hosting-related reasons.

If that's not it, I'll look into personal reasons (Maybe I deleted it?). Strange thing is that the apache2 config was still pointed at /var/wiki (and the wikis were running fine for weeks)

Comment: if you have auditing turned on, look at your audit logs.  if you don't have auditing turned on, consider turning it on for the future.  use the `last` command to see who was logged on between the times you last knew it to be there, and the time you noticed it was gone.  That may give you and idea as to who could have done it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing I can think of would *normally* remove a directory named like this. Either you deleted it by mistake *or* it is gone due to disk corruption *or* your site got compromised and it was removed maliciously.

If it is related to disk corruption, you might do a `fsck` and then look under `lost+found` directory on that partition - some files might be recovered.
If you find nothing this way, you can try [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/) or [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover some data.